# akamai with ruby on rails application application call time increases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic, akamai

I setup akamai with my ruby on rails application after using that application call time showing more into the newrelic but page load time is decreases , does[image] anyone knows how we can reduce application call time as it use to increase when I use that

You can see after 6 oct it will normal if I remove Akamai and setup it with direct application via changing into DNS

Comment: please check this out https://youtu.be/Ur9cMuh0wrM